# Cannot find reference 'X' in 'imported module Y'

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

PyCharm says it can't find the reference to some of my packages, even if the project interpreter is correctly set, and the packages that I'm trying to use are already installed using pip, on PyCharm's built in Package Installer.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eznO7.png

I have already tried:

- Switching between several Python interpreters
- Removing and reinstalling the packages
- Restarting PyCharm & Windows

example code (see the screenshot above):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tkinter import Tk

print(BeautifulSoup)
print(Tk)
```

what the PyCharm tooltip says:

```
Cannot find reference 'BeautifulSoup' in 'imported module bs4'
Cannot find reference 'Tk' in 'imported module tkinter'
```

what the actual output is, when running the program:

```
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
<class 'tkinter.Tk'>
```

Comment: Go into the terminal, you can do it from within python and type pip list. Does it list the packages? Another option is to go the the interpreter and look at the package list in the UI. It's possible you could be installing the packages to the wrong environment. Best way to handle this is to create and activate a virtual environment and then install the packages to that specific environment. Here's a link for review, https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Comment: I don't think that it's a problem with the interpreter itself, because running the program is actually possible and the output proves that these classes exist.
It should be something with PyCharm itself, or some defect in the way the IDE detects the Python interpreter.

Comment: Did you try file > invalidate caches and restart. Here is information regarding this process, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/cleaning-system-cache.html

Comment: @HMan06 thanks, I tried but it still doesn't work